# Resigning as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I've decided that it's time for me to step down as a moderator of this site. This has been something I've been thinking about for quite a while; it's a product of numerous events that have occurred over the past year or so. I've already communicated my decision to the people at Stack Exchange, and while I'm not sure when they will officially remove the diamond, I expect it will be soon, maybe this week.

I don't plan to be actively contributing here anymore, at least not in the short term, but my profile will remain in place and I'm not ruling out an occasional comment or post. If anyone wants to get in touch, my contact information is and will remain in my profile.

The other moderators and I discussed whether it makes sense to have an election to add new mods. We believe there's no immediate need for one, since the remainder of the team isn't having any trouble with the workload right now, but there might be one a few months down the road.

I'd like to express my gratitude to everyone who helped make moderating a rewarding experience for the past (almost) ten years!

Comment: No joking intended : this is like hearing your local saint is retiring.  Someone clone him on the way out, please.  Honestly I will miss your wisdom and balance around here.  Many thanks to you.

Comment: You're welcome StephenG, and thank you for the kind words!

Comment: Sept 18, 2020: dmckee & David Z are officially no longer Phys.SE moderators.

Comment: You've been through a lot in your time here, and more importantly were a source of strength for many others who were going through a lot. Kudos to you sir, and a sincere hope that you enjoy your well-earned rest!

Comment: Best wishes David, and thank you.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the kind note! Honestly I'm surprised (and maybe a little flattered) that you chimed in here. It was always a real pleasure to work with you and have your support while that lasted.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri You're welcome, and thanks for being a part of the community. It's been great to have you around.

Comment: _"it's a product of numerous events that have occurred over the past year or so"._

What events?

Comment: @DavidZ Would a better description be that you're 'retiring' from moderatorship? That carries the connotation that you've had a long and successful career which is coming to a natural close, which is... about right =).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I guess that would be accurate too. But I think I've seen it described as "resigning" more often than "retiring" when I've seen other mods (often on other sites) do this. And technically, as far as SE is concerned I do have the option to apply to become a mod again, which makes it less retirement-like. (Not that I currently have any plans to do so)

Comment: @DavidZ Technically, that's true of (almost) any retirement.

Answer (score 31):

I've been a contributor here for the past seven and a half years and in all that time, David Z, you have been a staple and pillar of the community. Your cool and collected moderating style has always represented our site well and I have no doubt that your input has been instrumental in shaping us into a community that can be respected as a source of physics answers.

While I'm sure everyone here is sorry to see you hang up your hat, not one of us could hold that decision in contempt. You have put in more than your fair share of effort into this site and served it well. We understand the desire to take a step back as things change and shift both on the network and in the world at large. We are all lucky to have had so many great years of contributions from you and could not hold your leaving us against you, seeing how you have given us so much already.

It pleases us to hear that you will still visit our community on occasion and we welcome whatever contributions you care to make. I think I speak for all of us at Physics.SE when, for all of the time that you intend to spend away from us, I say **thank you for your service and farewell; we wish you all the best with your future endeavors.**

Comment: Thanks for the kind words Jim, I appreciate it! I'll miss being part of the community with you around.

Answer (score 25):

A huge loss for the site, not only in terms of (outstanding) moderating expertise but also in terms of institutional memory.

Thank you for your years of kindness and for nurturing the site to its current amicable atmosphere.

Comment: Thanks ZeroTheHero, that's kind of you to say and much appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

David Z, I've not been participating much on Physics Stack Exchange much for years now, so I was most disheartened to come back exactly one day after you retired! You have been an amazing and vital support to this site for more years than you probably care to admit. I wish you the best on any new endeavors!

Comment: Thank you Terry! Unfortunate timing, I suppose. I'm glad to have been a part of this site with you.

Answer (score 1):

I've *very* much enjoyed my interactions with you in the h-bar and even chat rooms on other SE sites. You are one of the better moderators, and will be missed. You were very often the one moderator that responded with a decent speed, and therefore I do think having an election to add a new moderator would be a good idea, whether or not the other mods agree (they won't be able to see the perspective of the non-moderator user that gets their concerns addressed so quickly by DavidZ and otherwise would have to wait longer, especially if there's one fewer total moderator).